# The image will change to a file when it is added to the folder

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I have a little problem. I would like to add an image from a folder to a project so that I don't have a mess in the project. The images that I have directly in the project not in the folder . Do you know what to do? I want to change the images after clicking the button, that's why I want more images there
[image: How does it looks like]

My code where I want change Images, it works with Images inside project

```
 public void ChangeImg(Uri resourceUri,Image image)
        {
            StreamResourceInfo streamInfo =
          Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);
            BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
            var brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = temp;
            image.Source = brush.ImageSource;
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            ChangeImg(new Uri("images/timetable_Unselected.png",
            UriKind.Relative), img_Home_Unselected);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

did you add that image by drag and drop the file?
it has not become a file the problem is that it has not been loaded in the most appropriate way.

Try to add the file as a resource, to do that go to the project menu in the resource tab.
In that section add resource specifying the type and you should be good to go.
Later when you want to call the image from code you can find it in the resources that are easily accessible via code.

to call image via code search on stack is well documented.

Comment: Hello.In winforms it was enough to add the image to resources, where I saved the image, as in this case. Then it was enough to call  `Properties.Resources.SomeImage`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Problem solved!**
Click on the file -> Add -> Exististing File -> **SELECT ALL FILES**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).